# How to move an element in next line?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the button stay under the text? If I do a `<br>` the button goes outside the div. Why?

```css
.dropzone {
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
  <span>Drag and drop a file or</span>
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="text/plain" id="fileUpload" class="hide" />
  <label for="fileUpload" class="btn btn-primary-outline">Select file</label>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your button?

Comment: i mean the input button

Comment: Because of your line-height

Answer (score 2):

The input went outside of the div when you inserted a `<br>` tag, because you set the line height to 200px. A `<br>` represents a new line, apparently with a spacing of 200px to other lines. The following code displays the button under the `<span>`:

```css
.dropzone {
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    max-width: 100%;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
  <span>Drag and drop a file or</span><br>
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="text/plain" id="fileUpload" class="hide" />
  <label for="fileUpload" class="btn btn-primary-outline">Select file</label>
</div>
```

Comment: so the correct way is to use `height: 100%` instead? How did u center the text?

Comment: No, the correct way is to **not use `line-height`**. The text was already centered in your code with: `text-align: center`. I updated my answer and removed the `height: 100%` css rule.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `line-height:200px;` it will not push the button down 200px.
You can use a `<p>` tag instead of span and it will move the text under without needing the `<br>`.

```css
.dropzone {
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    max-width: 100%;   
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
  <p>Drag and drop a file or</p>
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="text/plain" id="fileUpload" class="hide" />
  <label for="fileUpload" class="btn btn-primary-outline">Select file</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please mention that you removed the `line-height` css rule from your css, which causes the behavior OP commented.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
.button {
  display: block;
}
```

This should position the button under the element behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `line-height` is what's pushing the button outside of the `div` when you insert a `<br>` after your text. I suggest removing it if you want to use the line break, as well as looking into flexbox or padding properties if you want to vertically align your `div` contents.

For example:

```css
.dropzone {
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  /*     line-height: 200px; */
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
  <span>Drag and drop a file or</span> 
  <span>
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="text/plain" id="fileUpload" class="hide" />
    <label for="fileUpload" class="btn btn-primary-outline">Select file</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added some css and br tag

```css
.dropzone {
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    max-width: 100%;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropzone span{
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
<span>Drag and drop a file or</span><br>
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="text/plain" id="fileUpload" class="hide" />
<label for="fileUpload" class="btn btn-primary-outline">Select file</label>
</div>
```